# Проблема при парсинге сайта гуггл переводчика. Jsoup

Tags: java, http, jsoup, https

Изначально я пытался пропарсить сайт translate.ru, все было  хорошо, но при парсинге translate.google.ru вылетает ошибка.

> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error
>   fetching URL. Status=403, URL=https://translate.google.ru/ at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:598)
>   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235) at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:224) at
>   http.RequestDemo.main(RequestDemo.java:14)

А вот вот весь код программы

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import  org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class RequestDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://translate.google.ru/").get();
        //System.out.println(doc.html());
        Elements metaElements = doc.select("span");
        //System.out.println(metaElements);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена. Для того что бы все работало надо поключаться через userAgent("/*Здесь передаем название браузера*/")

Comment: А пример кода бы еще поместить в ответ...